# Points disappear when zooming past certain scale in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, zoom

My points are disappearing when I zoom in past 300,000 in ArcMap.  I tried to repair geometry, but it doesn't fix anything?

I also checked the scale extents and those are turned off.  I can export the points to a new shapefile/feature class, but I'd like to not have to do that.

I'm using 10.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Try building or deleting/building the spatial index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up exporting the file and starting over with a new shape.  It seemed to work.  It could have been the spatial index since I ended up starting over.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with ArcMap, but do you have a scale range set on the feature? In the TOC right click on the feature and go to properties and view the General tab:

[image]

But I'm assuming this is not the case.

---

In ArcMap, go to the Customize --> ArcMap Options --> Display Cache and clear the cache.

---

This ESRI Knowledge Base article says to delete and rebuild your spatial index:

http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38839

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: I added a couple other suggestions. Deleting your display cache and ESRI recommends deleting and recreating the spatial index. Good luck.